# Spring Security 6 not calling my CustomAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat9

I have a Spring SecurityConfiguration defined like this:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.customAuthenticationProvider = customAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors(CorsConfigurer::disable) // Disable CORS
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/health", "/public/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**", "/events/**", "/competition/**").authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic());

        return http.build();
    }
   
}
```

The requests under /static and /public are being permitted correctly, however anything under /events, /api, /competition are hitting the AnnoymousAuthenticationFilter.
Here are the logs for a request to /events/1

```
    20:05:06.483 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /events/1
20:05:06.483 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
20:05:06.484 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.pr.golf.golfapp.controller.EventsController#getEvent(Long)
20:05:06.486 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.pr.golf.golfapp.controller.EventsController#getEvent(Long)
20:05:06.487 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.pr.golf.golfapp.controller.EventsController#getEvent(Long)
20:05:06.488 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.pr.golf.golfapp.controller.EventsController#getEvent(Long)
20:05:06.490 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /error
20:05:06.491 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
20:05:06.492 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
20:05:06.493 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
20:05:06.495 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
20:05:06.498 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
20:05:06.498 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
```

Comment: this is basic spring security. you are trying to access `GET /events/1` you are not authenticated so spring redirects you to `/error` (this is how basic spring boot error handling works and can be read in the spring boot error chapter which you should of read before asking here)  and sincle `/error` is not permitted, you get a 401. You havn't defined how you are going to authenticate, so how do you think spring security is magically going to call your `CustomAuthenticationProvider`

Comment: Tbh, writing custom security should be done after you have tried using the regular built in spring security login methods, and used the already prebuilt `AuthenticationProviders` if you dont know anything about spring security, dont try to build custom security first thing, security is complicated, and its usually very bad practice building custom security if you have no idea what you are doing. And if you still insist on doing it, then read the documentation.

Comment: The whole point of the CustomAuthentication is that it should call that to do the authentication, its ordered number 1 too.  The error should come when it calls the authenticate method of CustomAuthenticationProvider for anything under /events.

Comment: i'll explain this once again.... what type of `authentication`  basic auth, formlogin, supplied username password, opague token, jwt token, SAML, certificate, session cookie? You have not defined HOW the client should authenticate. So how would spring security know what type?

Comment: i suggest you read this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html and then try implementing FormLogin which is the most common so you understand https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html

Comment: It doesnt matter if its httpBasic or token.  I am using a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken provider, so I expect that whatever is passed in is matching that.

Comment: is matching what? still im going to repeat it once again and this is the last comment im writing since you dont seem to be reading them. How do you expect spring to know when to run your provider when you havnt configured how spring security should authenticate the user.

Comment: I dont and I beleive what Im looking for is a OncePerRequestFilter.  That way I can specify that it happens before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter then in the custom authentication filter I can explicitly set the authentication result on the SecurityContextHolder.  I guess my next problem is If I want to move from MVC and Tomcat to Reactor and Netty then I have to reconfigure this all over again....

Answer (score -1):

By using the following I can acheive it without explicitly configuring an authentication mechanism/protocol for the custom provider.

```
    public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

}
```

This way I can set the authentication on the SecurityContextHolder once I decided what type of authentication I want to do.  It also guarantees that whatever webClient I use with any Authorization header type set I can inspect and call the correct underlying function.